# jetback compose black background when using VideoView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-videoview

when i use this code to show Imageview in jetback compose it works normally

```
Column(
Modifier
.wrapContentHeight()
.fillMaxWidth(),
) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.size(180.dp).align(CenterHorizontally).padding(0.dp, 64.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),
        painter = painterResource(id = com.taxa.R.drawable.ic_phone_reg),
        contentDescription = ""
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(headerResource),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(bodyResource),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 10.dp),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
    )
}
```

[image]

but when i need to show a video from raw folder instead of image and replace image with videoview

```
{
    Column(
        Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        val path = "android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/" + videoResource
        CommonVideoView(
            path,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(180.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(CenterHorizontally)
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(headerResource),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(bodyResource),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 10.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun CommonWebView(urlToRender: String, modifier: Modifier) {
    AndroidView(factory = {
        VideoView(it).apply {
            setVideoPath(urlToRender)
            setOnCompletionListener {
                start()
            }
            start()
        }
    }, modifier = modifier.size(100.dp))
}
```

--
the video works normally but the background become black

[image]

what should i do to show the background white when i use VideoView?